# gource and ffmpeg reduce video size

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to create video with [gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/wiki/Videos). I succeed with the following command line:

```
gource $LOG_FILE --log-format custom --stop-at-end --caption-file ${FILENAME}_captions.log --caption-duration 3 --title $TITLE --seconds-per-day 0.7 --auto-skip-seconds 1 --date-format\
 "%d/%m/%y" --hide "mouse,progress" --user-scale 0.6 --caption-size 20 -1380x950 -o - | ffmpeg -y -r 60 -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm -i - -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420\
p -crf 1 -threads 4 -bf 0 $FILENAME.mp4
```

But the video are too big, 9Go for 4 min. How can I reduce the size with ffmpeg?

I use Fedora.

Comment: Others answers already addressed your `-crf 1`, but `-bf 0` makes little sense.  x264 only uses B frames when they will help overall quality.  If you need compat with ancient hardware players, use `-profile baseline`.  (One case where x264's b-frame decisions aren't optimal (or weren't in 2009?) is a series of not-very-similar still pictures, where lots of I macroblocks are needed: http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=145005)

Comment: Also, x264 auto-detects how many threads to use.  Only use `-threads` if you want it not to saturate all your CPUs.  (like if `gource` needs significant CPU time?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `-preset`

Use the slowest preset that is fast enough that it does not drop frames. You can see if `ffmpeg` is dropping frames in the console output (if I recall correctly). Presets are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow.

## `-crf`

Use the highest `-crf` value that still provides an acceptable quality level. Range is 0-51. 0 is lossless, 18 is generally considered to be visually lossless or nearly so, 23 is default, and 51 is worst quality. Using a value of 1 will likely result in a huge file.

#### Also see:

- [FFmpeg H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the same input file the initial size was 1.3Go and now only 39Mo.

Comment: ultrafast for anything but lossless is a bad idea.  `-preset superfast -x264-params cabac=0` is MUCH better quality per bitrate (RD), and almost as fast.

Answer (score 3):

You specify a preset and a quality value at the same time and by that overriding the preset.
I would also recommend you don't encode with ffmpeg while capturing as this would be pretty slow on most PCs.

The "error" in your ffmpeg commandline is the option `-crf 1`. `CRF` is a quality setting of x264 and the lower the value the higher the bitrate of the video will be. Setting it to `1` will make the video pretty much lossless. Just leave that command out and maybe use a preset like `medium` or `slow` and not `ultrafast` like you have right now to get a decent quality.